# Java & MongoDB - How to get the value of _id in a MongoDB document?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, server-side

I'm using the API specified here: `http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/Document.html`

Here's the code I have:

```
Document doc = collection.find(Filters.eq("field","value")).first();
String id = (String) doc.getString("_id"); // this line throws exception
```

I already checked that `doc` has a returned `Document` but I cannot access the value of `_id`.

The error says  this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: What's your scheme

Answer (score 2):

`_id` is an `ObjectId`, you should use this:

```
String id = doc.getObjectId("_id").toHexString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following:

```
doc.get("_id");
```

Comment: Just tried. The IDE throws an error saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert Object to String". Maybe I'll try `(String) doc.get("_id")`

Comment: Or actually `doc.get("_id").toString();`

Comment: Or `doc.get("_id", ObjectId.class))` if you want to get the `ObjectId` instance. 'Though if all you need is the hex string representation then `doc.get("_id").toString()` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run:

```
doc.get("_id").toString();
```

To get the literal ID.